# Using Google Maps API in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

Hey guys I've installed the SDK for google play services and have added the dependancies however I still get the error:

```
Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5+
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Heres my dependencies file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "team08.httpapp"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.+'
}
```

Comment: you don't have to add the `...play-services-maps:6.5.+'` that is handled in your `...play-services:6.5.+'`

Comment: @zgc7009 Oh cheers. Still can't find it.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `Still can't find it`? When you remove one of those dependencies (one more generic, one more explicit, but you only need one) what error do you get?

Comment: @zgc7009 Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5+

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, everything I am looking at looks good.

Comment: @zgc7009 is there another way to include Googlemaps API?

Comment: You can add it directly to your project and compile from your project libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Comment: This is a bug. I'm having the exact same issue and the setup is right.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "Google Repository" is installed in your SDK manager.

Answer (score -1):

Based on this Google blog post:
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html

I would remove `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'` and change the other line to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'`.